# Why shortcuts with hotkeys don't work anywhere except Desktop and Start Menu?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

> I have researched all over, but I couldn't find a legitimate reason for this problem.

The hotkeys assigned to shortcuts don't work unless they are placed on the Desktop or Start Menu.

If it doesn't work, why did Windows provide the option in the first place? Does it have any other purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the Desktop and Start Menu are loaded as part of Explorer. It has backwards compatibility with Windows 95 when it was added to compensate for people using hotkeys to launch programs coming from Dos and Windows 3.11.

Although explorer.exe is used for the desktop and start menu as well as browsing files on your computer, it would take considerably more resources if all shortcuts with hotkeys would have to be memorized. In addition, you can only have a few hotkeys maximum. I think 26 or so, as by then you have simply run out of all the possible hotkeys. So having it limited to those locations is by various reasons, but mostly legacy reasons.

There are plenty of alternatives though, such as a launcher.

Comment: I see.. Anyway AutoHotKey works fine